# Calculating FCS (CRC 16 CCITT)

Tags: serial-port, frame, checksum, crc16

I have this frame :

```
7E 01 FF 53 70 00 3D 7E
```

Where :

7E - Delimiter flag

01 - Destination address

FF - source address

53 - Data

70 - Data

00 - Data

3D - Check sum calculated as : (BYTE)(0 - ( 01+FF+53+70+00)

And this indication : 
Check sum : 1 byte check sum defined as 0x00 - {[DestinationAddress] + [SourceAddress] + [Body of Message]}

Checksum calculated according to CCITT CRC-16.

But I never get this result with this calculator : http://www.zorc.breitbandkatze.de/crc.html

How to do ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the documentation - there is no CRC used here.

To calculate the checksum convert the numbers in question to decimal and sum them together (01 + 255 + 83 + 112 + 0) = 451. Then take mod 256 of 0 - 451 to get the checksum byte.

In this case that would be -451 % 256 = 61 = 3D